# Does MS PowerBI directly connect with Azure's ML workbench?

Tags: azure-ml, powerbi

Someone wants me to try to see if I can establish a workflow for them using PowerBI and Azure's ML, then show them how to use it. The idea is to create kind of a seemless experience for them, so they done have to worry about coding or dealing with ETL, etc.

Right now I can access Azure but I have to go through some red tape to access the cloud version of PowerBI.

Does anyone happen to know if these 2 product services can be directly linked, such that the person I'm trying to help wouldn't have to worry about importing or exporting files (assuming I pipe the data into Azure's ML for them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can connect natively. You can manage data and then put it all in different services like it is showed next. As you can see you can use SQL database, blob storate and also PowerBI.
[image]

[Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-power-bi-dashboard/) you can find a tutorial on how to do streaming analytics with Azure and PowerBI.